# Java error: The url cannot be null ( netbeans and wampserver)

Tags: mysql, java

I'm creating a Java application (stock management) with NetBeans and WampServer, I create the `stock_db_connection` class and the `Login` class, and I want to test if it's work or not, when I click run file, the login window appear; I enter the username and password but when I click "Login", I get the following error:

```
The url cannot be null
The url cannot be null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stockmanagment.Stock_db_connection.exectionQuery(Stock_db_connection.java:58)
    at stockmanagment.Stock_db_connection.querySelectAll(Stock_db_connection.java:97)
    at database.Login.loginActionPerformed(Login.java:117)
    at database.Login.access$200(Login.java:10)
    at database.Login$3.actionPerformed(Login.java:79)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I don't know what is the problem, please can you help me...
This is the code of Login button.

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    rs = db.querySelectAll("utilisateur", "username='" + txt_username.getText()
    + "' and password='" + txt_password.getText() + " '");
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            username1 = rs.getString("username");
            password1 = rs.getString("password");
            hak = rs.getString("type");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    if (username1 == null && password1 == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "le nom utilisateur ou le mots de pass est incorrect");
    } else {
        if (hak.equals("directeur")) {
            Produits h = new Produits();
            h.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } else {
            Chauffeurs k = new Chauffeurs();
            k.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
    }                                     
}
```

Comment: This seems to be completely unrelated to database administration.

Comment: Try StackOverflow for this.

Comment: That error is caused by other code not shown here. Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)